# Making species map using km grid in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, attribute-joins

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.5, I am trying to make a species map to show the locations certain species are observed. I want to do this using kmgrid. I got quite far I think but now I am stuck.

I made a km grid for the netherlands giving every square kilometre a unique code. I also used this code in the database with the species. I couldn't join the two tables because in the species table te unique code was used multiple times so I made a pivot table to make sure all codes where unique.

[image: Excel pivot table]

[image: Attributetable after pivot]

After this I could link the data but now arc gis shows all species at once.

[image]

I can manualy select every species seperately but this will take a lot of time.

Is there another step I can take so I can use data driven pages for example?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I think a solution to this would involve Create Fishnet, and Spatial Join.  What were the precise steps (tools and parameter values) that you used in your workflow?

Comment: Did you try to join by location? Is the solution to relational features without a common ID

Comment: I can't understand your column headers (I don't read that language) but I think that doing a pivot table is robbing yourself of frequency in your distributions or simply reducing your species to just the first tabular occurrence, depending on what your columns actually mean, either way you're potentially destroying your data... spatial join now, summarise later.

Comment: Thank you, the names are just species names and kmhok is the unique code I made. The spatial join worked perfectly. I have over a 100 species to make a map for. Now I make them by using definition query to select per species. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: if i got you right, you're looking for this sort of hidden feature in ´spatial join()´ function, that allows multiple values to be rewritten. the following link explains this issue quite well: https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/spatial-joins-hidden-trick-or-how-to-transfer-attribute-values-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/

Comment: You need definition query to show column of interest, e.g. FOX is not null .

Comment: @dru87 I think that's worth you summarizing in a no coding answer.  I would probably have done the last step using a cursor rather than a field mapping but the asker does not seem to be using ArcPy.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you're looking for a way to join multiple fields (i.e. your species) to the km-grid you've created. This function is somewhat "hidden" in ArcGIS, as it's a part of the `SpatialJoin()` function (found in the Analysis Toolbox).

As [this link describes](https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/spatial-joins-hidden-trick-or-how-to-transfer-attribute-values-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/), try the following steps:

- Open Spatial Join. Select the km-grid as your target features, the species as your join features
- select JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY as the operational mode
- right-click on your species field in the field map list, click on properties
- in the properties menu, increase the length of the field to a sufficiently high number (i.e. 200) to hold all your species information
- select JOIN for your merge rule, and set a suitable delimiter (I'd recommend "," or ";")
- hit OK and select INTERSECT in the Spatial Join main window for the Match Option

This should then set up a new feature class that contains all the species per km-grid polygon, separated by the character you've selected. Export that table to a txtfile or to an Excelsheet and modify further as wished.